# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Tags: java, bouncycastle, websphere-8

I am facing issue in configuring Bouncy Castle with my `websphere`. I am working on pdf document signature and it requires dependency of Bouncy Castle. I am using `websphere v8.5`, `java 6` and `bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar`

Currently I have included this jar to my project lib and I am deploying it to WAS. So its throwing error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.

After getting this error I have tried to configure Bouncy Castle to `WAS` by putting `bcprov-jdk15on-1.47.jar` to `[WAS_HOME]/java/jre/lib/ext/` and updated `java.security`. After that when I am starting application server but server is not starting.

Can you please provide me guidance on this?

Comment: How do you build your war/ear?

Comment: Can we see the code where this error occurs

Comment: @kocko: I have developed stand alone pdf signature and its working properly. Then I have integrated that functionality with IBM Case manager Custom plugin. For this I have put the bouncy castle jar to the lib of my custom plugin project and registered it with build.xml.

Comment: Are you several years behind in patching? Please patch the sever to at least 8.5.5.x level.

Answer (score 3):

add this to pom.xml to overcome the following exception.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: 
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:432)
```

Bouncy Castle Provider » [1.46](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk16/1.46)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
    <version>1.46</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using maven to build the app, then please add this as dependency in pom.xml.

If you are using this jar as external reference from your File System, make sure to export it along with your war (in case of eclipse , you can set export option from build path lib )

Comment: I am using ant to build the application and its external jar reference is added to its build.xml

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to execute it in CMD, make sure to you specify `-providerpath` correctly.